# PHP check if multiple file upload is empty

Tags: php, file

In my code you have a choice of either uploading a file or not and if you don't it should just end the code, but if you do upload a file and select an appropriate pack name(which is a database name they created) then it is suppose to run the code and submit to file directory. But my problem is that in this line of code

```
if($_FILES['packFiles']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
```

it checks if file is not empty or "No errors" and it runs the code inside but because i have a "multiple file upload" like this

```
<input type="file" name="packFiles[]" multiple>
```

it skips it and ends the code. I noticed that when i removed the multiple part and it worked perfectly. So my question is if there is a way to check if its not empty while allowing users to upload multiple files. Here is my code.

PHP

```
   <?php
session_start();

 if(empty($_FILES) && empty($_POST) && isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post'){ //catch file overload error...
        $postMax = ini_get('post_max_size'); //grab the size limits...
        echo "<p style=\"color: #F00;\">\nPlease note files larger than {$postMax} will result in this error!</p>"; // echo out error and solutions...
        return $postMax;
    }

if(isset($_COOKIE['id'])){

    if($_SESSION['came_from_upload'] != true){

        setcookie("id", "", time() - 60*60);
        $_COOKIE['id'] = "";
        header("Location: developerLogin.php");
        exit;


    }
    echo "<h1> UPDATE PACK FILES INFORMATION</h1>";
    try{

        // new php data object 
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=magicserver', 'root', '');
        //ATTR_ERRMODE set to exception
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        }catch(PDOException $e){
             die("There was an error connecting to the database");   

        }
       $userid = $_SESSION['id'];
       $stmt = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM pack_profile WHERE pack_developer_id = :userid");
       $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
       $stmt->execute();
        echo "<h2> Please select the pack name you want to update!</h2>";


   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =="POST"){
         $token = $_SESSION['token'];

       if(!empty($_POST['packNameSelection'])){
            $price = addslashes(trim((int)$_POST['price']));
            $description = addslashes(trim($_POST['description']));
            $packname = addslashes(trim($_POST['pack_name']));

           $packNameSelection = $_POST['packNameSelection'];
           if(!empty($packname)){

               $stmtPacknameCheck = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM pack_profile WHERE pack_name = :packname");
               $stmtPacknameCheck->bindParam(':packname', $packname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $stmtPacknameCheck->execute();
               if($stmtPacknameCheck->fetch()){

                   echo "Packname entered is already in use... Please try again";
                   exit;
               }

               $stmtPackname = $handler->prepare("UPDATE pack_profile SET pack_name = :packname WHERE pack_name = :packNameSelection");
               $stmtPackname->bindParam(':packname', $packname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $stmtPackname->bindParam(':packNameSelection', $packNameSelection, PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $stmtPackname->execute();
           }

           if(!empty($price)){

               if(!ctype_digit($price)){

                    echo "PRICE ENTERED IS NOT AN INTEGER... PLEASE TRY AGAIN!";
                    exit;
                }

                $stmtPrice = $handler->prepare("UPDATE pack_profile SET pack_price = :price WHERE pack_name = :packNameSelection");
                $stmtPrice->bindParam(':price', $price, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmtPrice->bindParam(':packNameSelection', $packNameSelection, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmtPrice->execute();
           }

           if(!empty($description)){

               if(strlen($description) < 10){

                echo "Description field MUST to be GREATER than 10 characters!";
                exit;
            }

               $stmtDescription = $handler->prepare("UPDATE pack_profile SET pack_description = :description WHERE pack_name = :packNameSelection");
               $stmtDescription->bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $stmtDescription->bindParam(':packNameSelection', $packNameSelection, PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $stmtDescription->execute();

           }

           if(!empty($_FILES['packFiles']['tmp_name'])){

               $stmtPackCheck = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM pack_profile WHERE pack_name = :packNameSelection");
               $stmtPackCheck->bindParam(':packNameSelection', $packNameSelection, PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $stmtPackCheck->execute();
               $resultPack = $stmtPackCheck->fetch();

               $file_name = "";
               $packid = $resultPack['pack_id'];
                foreach($_FILES['packFiles']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error){

                     if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                        $errors[] = $_FILES['packFiles']['name'][$key] . ' was not uploaded.';
                        continue;
                    }
                    $pack_tmp = file_get_contents($_FILES['packFiles']['tmp_name'][$key]);
                $pack_filename = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\.]/", "_", strtolower($_FILES['packFiles']['name'][$key]));
                     $pack_filename = strtotime("now")."_".$pack_filename;
                    $file_name .= $_FILES['packFiles']['name'][$key].",";
                    //Insert into file directory
                    $dir = "devPacks/" .$userid."/".$packid;
                    if(is_dir($dir)==false){

                        mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
                    }
                    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['packFiles']['tmp_name'][$key],$dir.'/'.$pack_filename)){

                            die("an error occurred sending this file... Pleas try again later!");

                }


                }
           }

           die("ok");
       }else{

           echo "Please select valid value from dropdown list";
           exit;
       }
}
}


?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

    <select name="packNameSelection">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Pack Name</option>
    <?php

        while($result = $stmt->fetch()){
     echo "<option value=\"" . $result['pack_name'] . "\">" . $result['pack_name'] ."</option>";
   }


    ?>
    </select>

    <br>
    Pack Name: <input type="text" name="pack_name" placeholder="Your pack name">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id">
    <br></br>
    Price: <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="If FREE enter 0">
    <br></br>

    Descripion: <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="description" placeholder="Description..."></textarea>
    <br></br>
    Select Pack Files: <input type="file" name="packFiles[]" multiple>
    <br></br>
    <!--Select Pack Screenshots/Video: <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple> -->
<br></br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: you need to loop through `$_FILES['packFiles']` so before this line `if($_FILES['packFiles']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){` you need to do something like `foreach($_FILES['packFiles'] as $fileUpload){`

Comment: wait but what if the user doesn't submit any data? I will get an error cause files aren't there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
// check and see whether is empty
if(!empty($_FILES['packFiles']['name'])){

    foreach($_FILES['packFiles']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error){
        $filename = file_get_contents($_FILES['packFiles']['tmp_name'][$key];
        // check file_get_contents
        if($pack_tmp = file_get_contents($filename) !== false){

            $pack_filename = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\.]/", "_", strtolower($_FILES['packFiles']['name'][$key]));
            $pack_filename = strtotime("now")."_".$pack_filename;
            $file_name .= $_FILES['packFiles']['name'][$key].",";
            //Insert into file directory
            $dir = "devPacks/" .$userid."/".$packid;
            if(is_dir($dir)== false){
                mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
            }

            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['packFiles']['tmp_name'][$key],$dir.'/'.$pack_filename)){

            } else {
                die("an error occurred sending this file... Pleas try again later!");
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    //error any error message u want.
}
```

Check the file before foreach loop

Comment: Thank you but when it is "empty" i get this error "( ! ) Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\wamp64\www\MT\developer_packupdater.php on line 110
"

Comment: Because i have other inputs that i check if not empty and i run the code and i get that error. I didn't show the other code cause its too long and i wanted to focus on the file

Comment: I added this one to control the error  if($pack_tmp = file_get_contents($filename) !== false)

Answer (score 7):

We can use this for a multiple file input:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['packFiles']['name'][0])){ 
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( isset($_FILES['packFiles']) and count($_FILES['packFiles']['tmp_name']) > 0 )
{
   // Your code
}
```